# c++ program not running properly from outside code::blocks

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I am using Code::Blocks and MinGW to build c++ programs. When I run the compiled program in Code::Blocks, it works perfectly. But when I tried to run the same exe from outside Code::Blocks, the program is not running and giving two errors:

1. The program can't run because libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll is missing from your computer.
2. The program can't run because libstdc++-6.dll is missing from your computer.

I have seen answers to other SO questions, but none of the answers worked for me.

What I have tried:

1. Copy and paste the two files from C:/MinGW/bin to the folder where the exe is located.

   -This works fine but It becomes awkward to copy and paste these files to all your projects again and again.
2. Set the PATH variable to C:/MinGW/bin.
3. In the compiler and debugger settings dialog, go to linker settings>>other linker options and add the line `-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++` there.

***Edit*** I am adding images of compiler flags I can find:
[image: Page 1]
[image: Page 2]
[image: Page 3]

I have set the path in following way:
[image: Path]

(Note that I have the MinGW installation directory in D drive as the name of MinG).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218343/discussion-on-question-by-praneet-dixit-c-program-not-running-properly-from-ou). If you are asked a clarification question, you should not reply in the comments. Instead, [edit] your question.

Comment: It looks like you didn't actually do option 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

- build a completely static version (`--static`compiler flag)
- build using `-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc` as linker flags
- copy the files `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll` (and any other dependancies if any) to the same folder as your `.exe` file

Comment: those things were already mentioned in the question

Comment: Thanx, I had actually done these thing, but now the problem is solved. There was some problem with the path.

Comment: @PraneetDixit Note that you may have fixed your `PATH` to make it work on your system, but if you want to distribute your `.exe` to run on other systems you should also provide copies of the dependancies (`libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` and `libstdc++-6.dll`)